# Adding new data to XML File

Tags: java, xml, append, writer

I've got an android application which the user can input data and save it saves as an xml file on the device. I tried using different libraries to write the data to an xml file but I struggled using them. So therefore I made my own method which passes in a LinkedHashMap with the keys being the xml tags. It works perfectly fine but when user comes back to the application and saves new data I want it to be appended to the xml file. My trouble is I can't delete the closing tag in the xml file to add new data. Below is the method for creating xml file. Any help is much appreciated.

```
public static void createxml(LinkedHashMap<String, String> map, String root) {

    String s = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>";
    StringBuilder sb = null;

    sb = new StringBuilder(s);
    sb.append("<");
    sb.append(root);

    sb.append(">");

    if (fileExists = false) {
        sb = new StringBuilder("<Soparc>");

    }

    for (String key : map.keySet()) {
        sb.append("<");
        sb.append(key);
        sb.append(">");

        sb.append(map.get(key));

        sb.append("</");
        sb.append(key);
        sb.append(">");
    }

    sb.append("</");
    sb.append(root);
    sb.append(">");

    String st = sb.toString();
    try {

        BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(dataFile,
                true));
        output.write(st);
        output.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. *Just an advice:* Don't forget to escape special `xml` symbols. For this purposes you can use something like `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(...)` method.
2. Answering direct you question: unfortunatelly, if you want do this *carefully*, you have to parse your previous `xml` structure into some DOM (Document Object Model), update it with new user's data and write it into `xml` again.